# How to customize ServiceStack DateTime display format in its HtmlFormat snapshot

Tags: c#, servicestack

It looks like servicestack v4 (https://servicestack.net/) display DateTime in a yyyy/MM/dd format without showing the time portion at all. (see the following screenshot)

[image: Default DateTime display in ServiceStack snapshot]

How can I set the snapshot DateTime display format to display time as well?

The snapshot web page is rendered by one of its "Plugins" (HtmlFormat plugin). Or is there any way we can customize the HtmlFormat plugin to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show full dates you can just append `#show=fulldates` to the query string.

Otherwise you can always customize Html Format by providing your own copy of with the [Virtual File System](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes#the-virtual-filesystem) by providing your own local copy of:

- [/Templates/HtmlFormat.html](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Templates/HtmlFormat.html)

Comment: #show=fulldates does the trick. Overriding the htmlformat might be a little too much for now. Many thanks to the servicestack master!